# Messaging app with end-to-end encryption, usable in China

Tags: gratis, android, chat, encryption, privacy

[End-to-end encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption) has become a basic feature of messaging apps. WhatsApp was banned from China after implementing it. So, is there any end-to-end encrypted chat app which is usable right now in China (PRC)?

- End-to-end encryption (preferably audited, not just claimed)
- Runs on Android and iOS
- Reliably usable within People's Republic of China without a VPN
- Available in English and Chinese
- Reasonably user-friendly (novices can set it up and use it without external help)
- Free

Using a normal messaging app combined with an encryption+obfuscation tool would work, but please only propose such a solution if it is provides a user-friendly interface that hides the encryption and copy/pasting steps, and only shows messages.

Comment: I'm not sure how "reliably" a feature can be offered in a location where that feature does not comply with local laws.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I don't think there is an explicit law about this. But if there is one, I would be very glad to have that law's number/reference, thanks a lot! ^^

Comment: As long as your country don't like a specific technology (banned), you might not able to find anything that use that technology and also comply to your country's law. So you might to migrate to another country, right?